# Linq update query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to update an existing record. I also have debugged my code. The int id variable gets the value, but I don't know why my record doesn't updated.

```
SQLDBDataClassesDataContext dContext = new SQLDBDataClassesDataContext();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["fname"]))
        {
            FirstNameTextBox.Text = Request.QueryString["fname"];
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["lname"]))
        {
            LastNameTextBox.Text = Request.QueryString["lname"];
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["cellnum"]))
        {
            CellNumberTextBox.Text = Request.QueryString["cellnum"];
        }
    }
}

protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    var updatequery1 = dContext.PersonalDetailTables
        .Where(pd => pd.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();

    if (updatequery1 != null)
    {
        updatequery1.FirstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
        updatequery1.LastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
        updatequery1.CellNumber = CellNumberTextBox.Text;
        dContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to display a message in the if and the else of that part, see what message is displayed so you know if it even gets in the if statement.

Comment: Are you sure you using the DataContext properly? It's not clear from your code what is context and where it came from.

Comment: @SynerCoder.. it gets in the if(updatequery1!= null) clause..
but here, the value remains same and are not changed

Answer (score 0):

if (updatequery1 != null)

is updatequery1 null? If it's now, it'll just skip right over. Setup a breakpoint and step through.

Alternatively, change .SingleOrDefautl to .Single instead. This way if nothing's found, u'll get an exception, and u'll know what's up.

Comment: umm, i changed the singleordefault to .single. 
but one thing, the updatequery1 is not null. it goes into the if clause. 
*NOTHING HAPPENED* :/

Answer (score 0):

Call `dContext.InsertOnSubmit(fooentity)` method before calling `dContext.SubmitChanges();`.

For example.

```
 var ctx = DB.fooDB;
        fooobj.fooName= bar.fooName;
        fooobj.fooID= bar.fooID;
        if (fooobj.fooID== 0)
            ctx.Locations.InsertOnSubmit(bar);
        ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I`ve got my Solution..
the only problem was of if(!ispostback) issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
context.InvProductStockMasters
       .Update(ps => ps.LocationID.Equals(invStockAdjustmentHeader.LocationID) 
                  && ps.ProductID.Equals(invStockAdjustmentDetail.ProductID), 
               ps => new InvProductStockMaster 
                          { Stock = ps.Stock - invStockAdjustmentDetail.OrderQty });
```